# Submit not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form method="post" name="frm_no_kids" class="getstarted" action="step1.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="price_value" name="fee" value="<?php echo encrypt(499); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="divorce_type" name="divorce_type" value="no_kids">
    <a class="btn border-btn yellow-btn started-hover" title="Get Started" href="javascript:frm_no_kids.submit();">Get Started </a> 
</form>
```

I have this link and it is not working. This give me error like.

> TypeError: frm_no_kids.submit is not a function

Comment: Don't use inline events like that, it's bad practice. Use an external event handler

Comment: But for now, just give me a solution for this error.

Comment: @neha910 You should take the suggestion positively.

Comment: @Tiger, Yes definately but that time i was in hurry, and thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an id in your form and called a function on anchor tag click to submit your form data  :

```
 <form method="post" name="frm_no_kids" id="frm_no_kids" class="getstarted" action="step1.php">
        <input type="hidden" id="price_value" name="fee" value="<?php echo encrypt(499); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="divorce_type" name="divorce_type" value="no_kids">
        <a class="btn border-btn yellow-btn started-hover" title="Get Started" href="javascript:;" onclick="submitData()">Get Started </a> 
 </form>
 <script>
       function submitData(){
            document.getElementById("frm_no_kids").submit();
       }
 </script>
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks alot, not it is working fine. Thanx once again :) @Ravi

Answer (score 0):

```
   document.getElementsByName('frm_no_kids')[0].submit();
```

Check if this helps

```
<form method="post" name="frm_no_kids" class="getstarted" action="step1.php">
                    <input type="hidden" id="price_value" name="fee" value="<?php echo encrypt(499); ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="divorce_type" name="divorce_type" value="no_kids">
                  <a class="btn border-btn yellow-btn started-hover" title="Get Started" href="javascript:document.getElementsByName('frm_no_kids')[0].submit();">Get Started </a> 
                  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to use an actual submit button in the form instead of a hyperlink that acts like a submit button. You can use `<input type="submit">` or `<button type="submit">` if you want more control over display/formatting.

If you are set on using a non-submit button (like your hyperlink), then it would be best to give the form its own ID:

```
<form method="post" id="frm_no_kids" name="frm_no_kids" class="getstarted" action="step1.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="price_value" name="fee" value="<?php echo encrypt(499); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="divorce_type" name="divorce_type" value="no_kids">
    <a class="btn border-btn yellow-btn started-hover" title="Get Started" href="javascript:document.getElementById('frm_no_kids').submit();">Get Started </a> 
</form>
```

As was mentioned in the comments, using an event listener is MUCH better:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="frm_no_kids" name="frm_no_kids" class="getstarted" action="step1.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="price_value" name="fee" value="<?php echo encrypt(499); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="divorce_type" name="divorce_type" value="no_kids">
    <a id="frm_no_kids_submit" class="btn border-btn yellow-btn started-hover" title="Get Started" href="#">Get Started </a>
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("frm_no_kids_submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("frm_no_kids").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to your From and use that ID in your javascript

```
 <form method="post" name="frm_no_kids" id="frm_no_kids" class="getstarted" action="step1.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="price_value" name="fee" value="<?php echo encrypt(499); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="divorce_type" name="divorce_type" value="no_kids">
    <a class="btn border-btn yellow-btn started-hover" title="Get Started" href="javascript:;" onclick="submitData()">Get Started </a> 
 </form>
 <script>
   function submitData(){
        document.getElementById("frm_no_kids").submit();
   }
 </script>
```